# Set CursorPosition in Editor Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

How can we set `CursorPosition` in `Editor`. We can set `CursorPostion` in `Entry`, but how to set it in `Editor`? I know we can do it using Custom Renderer in Xamarin Forms, but how to implement it?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the reason to downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot set `CursorPosition` in `Editor` as we set it in `Entry`. We need to use **Custom Renderer**.

Using Custom Renderer makes most of the native functions and implementations possible in Xamarin Forms.

To set Cursor Position in `Editor` in Xamarin Forms.
This answer may be a bit lenghthier for beginners like me so please bear with me.

In your **Shared Project** add a Class **EditorExtended.cs**

```cs
public class EditorExtended : Editor
{
}
```

In your **XAML** Page add namespace for reference

```xml
<xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:ApplicationName.FolderNameThatContainsEditorExtended class">

<!-- If EditorExtended.cs is in "Controls" Folder-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Controls">
            
             ...

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">             
        <Local:EditorExtended x:Name="CustomEditor"></Local:EditorExtended>
    </StackLayout>
```

- Now in your **Android Project** add Custom Renderer. Make a folder and add **EditorRendererExtended.cs**

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EditorExtended), typeof(EditorRendererExtended))]
namespace MyApplication.Droid.PlatformSpecific.ExtendedControls
{
    public class EditorRendererExtended : EditorRenderer
    {
        public EditorRendererExtended(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.RequestFocus();                
                Control.SetSelection(Control.Text.Length);                
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

- Similarly in **UWP Project** Make a folder and add Custom Renderer in Platform Specific code.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EditorExtended), typeof(EditorRendererExtended))]
namespace MyApplication.UWP.PlatformSpecific.ExtendedControls
{
    public class EditorRendererExtended: EditorRenderer
    {
        public EditorRendererExtended()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Pointer);
                Control.SelectionStart = Control.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I haven't tested in **iOS**, but the method will be similar. Just add **EditorRendererExtended.cs** class in Platform Specific folder in iOS. This code is not tested, you are free to edit the answer if you know the solution. Here is the code I have implemented, but not tested.

```cs
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(EditorExtended), typeof(EditorRendererExtended))]
namespace MyApplication.iOS.PlatformSpecific.ExtendedControls
{
    public class EditorRendererExtended : EditorRenderer
    {
        public EditorRendererExtended()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                // just change this statement to the one that works.
                Control.SelectedTextRange = Control.GetTextRange(fromPosition: Control.BeginningOfDocument, toPosition: Control.BeginningOfDocument);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to include the below statement in all the Platform Specific code that you want to target, otherwise it won't work

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EditorExtended), typeof(EditorRendererExtended))]
```

**EditorRendererExtended** is different for each platform, you can change its name like **EditorRendererExtendedAndroid** or **EditorRendererExtendedUWP** for better understanding. I have just named them similar as I find naming them differently is not needed and makes it unnecessarily lengthy.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, I want to mark it as an answer, but don't you know Stackoverflow does not allow to Mark as Answer if I post Question and its Answer immediately? When I click Mark as Answer, it says *"You can accept your own answer tomorrow"*. Please remove the downvote if you have downvoted the Question and the answer.

Comment: You just need wait for two days .You could mark yourself.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, Yes I know that, then why did you say to mark as an answer? I know I can mark it as an answer within 2 days, I had posted the Question and the Answer yesterday, and I need to wait for 1 more day to mark as an accepted answer.