# how to programmatically select text in a Xamarin Forms Editor

Tags: android, xamarin, editor, custom-renderer

New-ish to Android and Xamarin, working in VS 2019, Xamarin Forms v4.8 ...

In my project, I have implemented a custom renderer for an Editor that provides a read-only Editor in which **the user** can select and copy text. Works great, with customized context menu (removing Cut and Paste options). Thank you Anna Domashych! (https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-in-xamarin-forms-69d09276d580)

I also want to provide a search function, where user enters text to be found (in an Entry or SearchBar), and the app finds **and selects** the found text, and then scrolls the found text into view, if necessary.

But I see no way to have the app select text in the Editor. An Entry has *CursorPosition* and *SelectionLength* properties, which I presume can be used to programmatically select text, but an Editor does not seem to have these properties. Call me crazy, but that fact seems particularly odd to me!

I was hoping I could extend my custom renderer, but custom renderers seem to provide a mechanism to set behavior-type properties that are not exposed in the cross platform Xamarin view (such as, *SetTextIsSelectable*). That is, it seems that a custom renderer cannot provide a means to set properties on the underlying Android control, from code in the shared project (dynamically?). In particular I am interested in the **setSelection(int start, int stop)** method of the Android EditText view.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73176/how-to-get-selected-text

Comment: @Cfun Thanks for the response, but the subject discussed in the post that you have linked to is about an **Entry** view. An Entry is for a single line of text, and it has _CursorPosition_ and _SelectionLength_ properties. I am trying to work with the **Editor** view, which handles multi-line text and does not have properties similar to the Entry

Comment: To set the cursor position of `Editor` in Xamarin Forms, try using the `Control.SetSelection` command in the custom renderer class. Check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623756/set-cursorposition-in-editor-xamarin-forms

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT  TY for the response (sorry for my delayed reply, I didn't see notification of your comment). I thought I'd do something in the custom renderer, but I don't see how to do it _on demand_. The post at the link you provided sets the Control.SelectionStart property in the OnElementPropertyChanged event. I need to be able to set selection start and length in real time, during user interaction. Tried doing this with dependency service; it works, but it's gawd-awful ugly. Also when I set a selection, the Editor opens the keyboard ... another problem (my editor is read-only)